# Undefinded control sequence \Chi

Tags: xetex, symbols

I'm compiling with XeLaTeX and in my document, when I put \Chi, or \Alpha, or any normal symbol it raises the error `Undefined control sequence`
This is my preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
```

Update:
I added `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, now there is no error but in the PDF there is a white space (Because Arial doesnt have greek letters). How can I set a different font for unicode-math?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since an uppercase Greek Chi is indistinguishable from X (and the same for Alpha), there's no command for them by default. The commands `\Chi` and `\Alpha` are defined if you load `unicode-math`, but there's no Unicode math font compatible with Arial.

Comment: And can I use a different font for the text and for Unicode-Math?

Comment: Yes, of course. But I can be sure the result is not pretty; but not worse than what you already get.

Comment: Nevermind, is pretty logical. \setmathfont works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for `\Chi` and `\Alpha`, because the glyphs are not distinguishable from “X” and “A”.

However, the standard TeX convention is to typeset uppercase Greek letters in upright shape. Doing

```
\newcommand{\Chi}{\mathrm{X}}
\newcommand{\Alpha}{\mathrm{A}}
```

in your setting would do no good, because the font corresponding to `\mathrm` would be Arial, unless you also do

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
```

Alternatively, use `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\setmainfont{Arial}

%\setmathfont{...} % there's no math font compatible with Arial

\begin{document}

Some text and $\Alpha\ne\Chi$.

\end{document}
```

[image]