# Summation index x in (set inclusion) big chi

Tags: indexing, greek

I am trying to write `\sum_{x \in \Chi, y \in \Upsilon}` to denote a summation whose index is with small x in big Chi, and small y in big Upsilon (summation over all possible values of two discrete random variables X, Y that take values in big chi and big upsilon). However, writing `\Chi` right after writing `\in` causes an undefined control sequence. How could I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  "Big Chi" has the same appearance as a capital "X".  Greek capital letters that aren't visually different from Latin letters aren't separately defined, originally for reasons of space.  You might provide your own definition though: `\newcommand{\Chi}{\mathrm{X}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefinded control sequence \Chi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319960/undefinded-control-sequence-chi-xelatex)